# jQuery, Slide Left div with text

Tags: jquery

I am trying to slide the #text-slidein div slide left from a hidden state.
I must have tried all variations but could not get it to work.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#top-2").animate({
        "top": "0px"
    }, 1500, 'easeOutExpo');
    $("#btm-2").animate({
        "top": "0px"
    }, 1500, 'easeOutExpo', function() {
        $("#top-1").animate({
            "top": "0px"
        }, 1500, 'easeOutExpo');
        $("#btm-1").animate({
            "top": "0px"
        }, 1500, 'easeOutExpo', function() {
            $("#top-3").animate({
                "top": "0px"
            }, 1500, 'easeOutExpo');
            $("#btm-3").animate({
                "top": "0px"
            }, 1500, 'easeOutExpo', function() {
                $("#row-top").animate({
                    "top": "-25"
                }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
                $("#row-btm").animate({
                    "top": "25px"
                }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
                $("#text-slidein").animate({
                    width: 'toggle'
                }, 350, 1000, function() {
                    $(".fade").fadeOut(1000, function() {
                        $("#menu-nav").fadeIn(1000);
                        $("#news-box").fadeIn(1000);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The closest I got the slider working was when I used the following slide function:

```
$("#text-slidein").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 2000, function(){
```

For some reason, using this code, the slider would work once and then the slider would not show and all I see is a blank space where is used to slide in.

```
$("#text-slidein").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 2000, function(){
```

I have a [sample on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/SPVXw/5/)

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted in your question is not the same code that you posted in the jsfiddle, regarding the code in the jsfiddle, the issue is that you're calling

```
                $("#text-slidein").show('slide', {
                    direction: 'right'
                }, 2000, function() {
                    $(".fade").fadeOut(1000, function() {
                        $("#menu-nav").fadeIn(1000);
                        $("#news-box").fadeIn(1000);
                    });
                });
```

and that signature of show is jQueryUI specific but jQueryUI isn't referenced. When I checked jQueryUI it seems to work.

Comment: Everything seems to work, however, you can't see the #text-slidein div tag sliding in from the right. Can anyone suggest why it won't work?

Comment: Hmm, odd, I see #text-slidein slide in from the right in Chrome 20, FF 14, and IE 9. Here's the jsfiddle I'm looking at, updated to have jQueryUI checked... http://jsfiddle.net/SPVXw/7/

Comment: MHollis, thanks for coming back for your help. I appreciate it. I actually went and tried it again. It seems to work this time. Added the jQuery UI link this time. Everything show up and the animation is more fluid that than kei's method. Thanks again for being a great help getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AsJ2u/)

Made a few changes to your code:

css:

```
#text-slidein {
    top: 260px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #888;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 0px;
    height:8px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:-800px
}
```

jQuery:

```
        $("#text-slidein")
            .animate({
                width:800,
                marginLeft:0
          }, 2000, function() {
              $(".fade").fadeOut(1000, function() {
                  $("#menu-nav").fadeIn(1000);
                  $("#news-box").fadeIn(1000);
              });
          });
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I noticed that your animation comes from the left and the animation seems to be choppy where the text does not slide as an entire line rather fills in as it slides in. I would like the text line to just slide in smoothly from the right to left. Thanks.

Comment: kei, I went back and made the #text-slidein css width 800px and the margin-left: 800px to make the slide in come from right to left.

Comment: kei, I went back and made the #text-slidein css width 0 and the margin-left: 800px to make the slide in come from right to left. However, as soon as the display: none; is applied to the #text-slidein div, I no longer see the slide in animation. Is this method the optimal for my method?